# why doesn't the script work this way?

Tags: javascript

Following is a statement that should run according to me when the HTML page loads.

```
document.getElementById("name_field").value = "JavaScript";
```

But this does nothing.If i try to do the same thing the different way :

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
document.getElementById("name_field").value = "JavaScript";
}
```

Then this works fine.

What is wrong with the first script.?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="valtest.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<label>Enter your name&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="name_field" /></label> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"Following is a statement that should run according to me when the HTML page loads"* - explain...

Comment: He did exlain. He wrote one line of code that does not work, but when adding it to the onload, it works. He just doesn't understand how the DOM works and wants to understand why is that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Onload runs after the HTML has been rendered in the page. So in your first example the element is not yet available for JavaScript processing.

Most use "document ready", which means the document has been rendered.

jQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   init()
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean after, not before.

Comment: By the time `load` fires, the document has pretty much been rendered. `DOMContentLoaded` fires *before* `load`. One can use `getElementsById` inside *both* handlers.

Comment: onload runs as soon at the page gets to that point. It means the page is loaded, but it may not have had time to render it fully. You'll expecially notice this on slower browsers, like IE7.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - agreed, but for most uses it is preferable to use DOM ready over `window.onload` so one does not have to wait for all resources to be loaded before the page is interact-able.

Comment: @Diodeus Page rendering is irrelevant here. What's important is whether or not the DOM tree is available.

Comment: I think you should explain that you are using the jQuery library. From the looks of it this might confuse the person if he doesn't know about jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML probably looks like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("name_field").value = "JavaScript";
</script>
<!--
More
code
here
-->
<input id="name_field" value="Static">
```

If that's the case, when the JavaScript is run **there is no element with the ID "name_field" in the DOM yet**.

`window.onload` is executed only *after* the entire DOM has been loaded and parsed ... which is why running the function then works.  (It would also work if it was attached to any other event handler that ran after the DOM was loaded, or even if the order of the `script` and `input` tags were reversed.)

Answer (score 0):

The element with id 'name_field' isn't available in the DOM yet because the whole document gets loaded in the sequencial order.

The second example will execute once the document has been loaded and your element is available.

Answer (score 0):

the javascript in your first sample execute immediately, before any DOM has rendered.  You have to wait for the DOM to render before you try to operate on it, which you are doing in your second sample.

Answer (score 0):

The first script may or may not work depending on where it is placed within your HTML. If the script is before the field itself (the `<input id="name_field" />`), the script will run before the browser acknowledges the existence of the field, so it will do nothing (actually, it should throw an error stating that you are trying to access the `value` property of an undefined object).

The second version runs after the page finishes loading. By then, the browser already knows about your field, to the script works.